# Confirmation: does "Cocoa-Touch framework" only support for iOS8 or later?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, ios8

Refer to the title, how about my app running in iOS7 if my deployment target is iOS7? Will it crash or throw some unexpected runtime error?

Currently I got the following error:

```
ld: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework) for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: It sounds like you've written your own dynamic framework and added it to your project. That's a new Xcode 6 / iOS 8 feature and yes, I'm pretty sure you can't read it back to iOS 7.

Comment: Good discussion here: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1480